# Highlight selected option from dropdown

Tags: php

Iam using PHP codeigniter framework. Value is set to select dropdown as below

```
<select class="form-control";>
  <option <?php if($d1 == 'native') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='native' >native</option>
  <option <?php if($d1 == 'migrated') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='migrated' >migrated</option>
</select>
```

for each row in table there is select option like above. I want to  highlight option with color if option is set to migrated on page load. 
I tried like below

```
<select class="form-control";>
  <option <?php if($d1 == 'native') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='native' >native</option>
  <option <?php if($d1 == 'migrated') { echo 'selected'; echo 'style="<color:red>"' }?> value='migrated' >migrated</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are not using proper syntax for style; you are missing a semicolon; and selected and style will be together making it useless. Try:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option <?php if($d1 == 'native') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='native' >native</option>
    <option <?php if($d1 == 'migrated') { echo 'selected style="background-color:red"' }?> value='migrated' >migrated</option>
</select>
```

Although to me it is easier to read inline conditions as the following:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option <?php echo $d1 == 'native' ? 'selected' : ''; }?> value='native' >native</option>
    <option <?php echo $d1 == 'migrated' ? 'selected style="background-color:red"' : ''; }?> value='migrated' >migrated</option>
</select>
```

Comment: First one highlights option 'migrated' in option list when I click on select. I want to highlight it on page load. when it shows selected options from DB

Comment: try using `background-color: red;` instead. The logic is correct, but maybe the element and/or the rule to apply the CSS style is not right

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer - try applying the style to the `<select>`, instead of the `<option>`

Comment: Thanks. But in this case it highlights all other options in that select. If I expand dropdown then all options are red

Comment: in that case let's put it back to the option, but keep the background-color rule, instead of just color

Comment: Thanks. It works with slight change. I applied background white to all option and red to select. As it was applying red to all.

Answer (score 1):

your styling is wrong

```
<select class="form-control";>
  <option <?php if($d1 == 'native') { echo 'selected'; }?> value='native' >native</option>
  <option <?php if($d1 == 'migrated') { echo 'selected'; echo 'style="color:red"'; }?> value='migrated' >migrated</option>
</select>
```

you don't need the brackets `<>` inside the inline style and don't forget semicolon `;`